# Writing a function to get the mode of a vector after adjusting the frequency

Tags: r, function, tidyverse, simulation, mode

I am interested in simulating 10000 samples of size 100 of discrete numbers from 1 to 5. For each of these samples I am interested in calculating the mode using R. However, prior to the calculation of the mode I have to multiply the frequencies corresponding to 1 and 5 **(for samples that have 1 or 5 in them)** **only** by 2. Thereby the mode will be calculated based on the adjusted frequencies (i.e. adjusted frequencies for 1 and 5 only). I have written a code for this. However the processing time is very high and as a result the code runs for a long time and R crashes ultimately.  Is there a way to simplify my code shown below, such that the processing time is less ?

My code is as follows

```
library(tidyverse)

freq_adj_mode<-function(x){
  tab<-table(x) %>% as_tibble()
  tab<-tab %>% mutate(adj.freq = ifelse(x %in% c(1,5),2*n,n))
  max.tab<-tab %>% filter(adj.freq==max(adj.freq))
  mode.response<-max.tab$x %>% as.numeric()
  adj.mode<-ifelse(length(mode.response)>1,mean(mode.response),mode.response[1])
  adj.mode
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Using `magrittr` and `purrr`

(Notice that if you load the `tidyverse`, `magrittr` must be loaded **afterwards**.)

```r
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)

freq_adj_mode_tv <- function(x) {
  x %>%
    table() %>% 
    extract(as.character(1:5)) %>%
    multiply_by(c(2, 1, 1, 1, 2)) %>%
    extract(. == max(., na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    names() %>%
    as.numeric() %>%
    mean(na.rm = TRUE)
}

x1 <- c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 5)
x2 <- c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
x3 <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5)
x4 <- c(2, 3, 4, 4)

freq_adj_mode_tv(x1)
# 1
freq_adj_mode_tv(x2)
# 1.5
freq_adj_mode_tv(x3)
# 2
freq_adj_mode_tv(x4)
# 4
```

## Using base R

```r
freq_adj_mode_baser <- function(x) {
  t <- table(x)[as.character(1:5)]
  t_adj <- t * c(2, 1, 1, 1, 2)
  t_adj_max <- t_adj[t_adj == max(t_adj, na.rm = TRUE)]
  mean(as.numeric(names(t_adj_max)), na.rm = TRUE)
}

x1 <- c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 5)
x2 <- c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
x3 <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5)
x4 <- c(2, 3, 4, 4)

freq_adj_mode_baser(x1)
# 1
freq_adj_mode_baser(x2)
# 1.5
freq_adj_mode_baser(x3)
# 2
freq_adj_mode_baser(x4)
# 4
```

## Benchmarking

```r
x <- sample(1:5, size = 10000, replace = TRUE)

bench::mark(
  freq_adj_mode(x),
  freq_adj_mode_tv(x),
  freq_adj_mode_baser(x)
)
# # A tibble: 3 × 13
#   expression                  min   median itr/se…¹ mem_a…² gc/se…³ n_itr
#   <bch:expr>             <bch:tm> <bch:tm>    <dbl> <bch:b>   <dbl> <int>
# 1 freq_adj_mode(x)         2.77ms   2.88ms     339.   726KB    25.0   149
# 2 freq_adj_mode_tv(x)    310.94µs 351.82µs    2764.   675KB    38.2  1085
# 3 freq_adj_mode_baser(x) 308.24µs 345.79µs    2881.   675KB    38.4  1274
# # … with 6 more variables: n_gc <dbl>, total_time <bch:tm>,
# #   result <list>, memory <list>, time <list>, gc <list>, and
# #   abbreviated variable names ¹​`itr/sec`, ²​mem_alloc, ³​`gc/sec`
# ℹ Use `colnames()` to see all variable names
```

Overall both alternatives run ~10x faster than `freq_adj_mode`. Of the two, `freq_adj_mode_baser` runs a bit faster than `freq_adj_mode_magrittr`, but it's not such great a difference. Style might be a better factor to choose one of the two alternatives.

Comment: Hey this works, but there are cases where 1 and 5 aren't in the sample, so I need the code in such a way that we need to multiply the frequency of 1 and 5 by 2 only is 1 and 5 are in the sample. This is one such example,                                                                                 
y<-rtnorm(100,1,1,1,5)
R<-round(y) # Here there is no 5 in the generate sample
Rmode<-freq_adj_mode(R)                                                                                                           so how can I refine the code ?

Comment: @AneethaDaniels, ok, so now I'm explicitly extracting all counts for 1 to 5. This introduces NAs if any number is not present in the input so we simply add the `na.rm` flag to `max` and `mean`. Answer updated accordingly.